# Hibernate Eager and Lazy loading with multiple ManyToOne relationship in an Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have Mandate class with 3 ManyToOne relationships

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MANDATE")
public class Mandate {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID", nullable=false)
private Long Id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_PERSONNE", nullable=false)
private Person person;

@Column(name="TITRE", nullable=false)
private String titre;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_LIGUE", nullable=false)
private League league;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_FEDERATION", nullable=false)
private Federation federation;
```

I got a person class with the OneToMany relationship

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Mandat> mandates;
```

this means that in my database a person  can have a mandat in either a league or a federation.
if he has a mandate in a league the federation field will be null, and the inverse is true.

But in my controller, when I do :

```
person.getMandates().size();
```

I always get a size of 0 elements.

the generated hibernate query is looking like this (I simplified it) :

```
SELECT  MANDATE.*, LEAGUE.*, FEDERATION.* 
from MANDATE 
inner join LEAGUE on  MANDATE.ID_LEAGUE = LEAGUE.ID
inner join FEDERATION on MANDATE.ID_FEDERATION = FEDERATION.ID WHERE MANDATE.ID_PERSON = 1;
```

It means that the generated request is looking for mandat fields with a non null League **and** Federation field, but in never true in my database.

I noticed that if I put a lazy loading to my fields I am getting the attempted results :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_LIGUE", nullable=false)
private League league;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_FEDERATION", nullable=false)
private Federation federation;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You've told Hibernate that the join columns are not nullable. But you also said that "if he has a mandate in a league the federation field will be null, and the inverse is true". How could the join column be not null and the league null at the same time. It's contradictory.

Comment: That was it, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person can have mandate for either league or federation which means either one of them will be null at any point of time. So, the nullable value shoud be true on joincolumns to make in happen. Hence you are not getting data for mandates.

When you use lazy load, a separate query specific to mandate alone will be fired without joining the federation table which will return the result when you invoke getMandates() on person object.